# Divide big class in subclasses

Tags: php, object-oriented

I have a very big class `Foo` that should be divided into `FooBar`, `FooUtility`, `FooBench`, `FooBranch`. Each of this "subclasses" should have different methods. So that if `Foo` has:

```
public function methodA();
public function methodB();
public function methodC();
public function methodZ();
```

Then I should be able to divide them as I want. For example:

```
FooBar:
public function __construct($param);
public function methodA();

FooUtility:
public function __construct($param);
public function methodB();

FooBench:
public function __construct($param);
public function methodZ();

FooBranch:
public function __construct($param);
public function methodC();
```

But I should be able to call `methodB()` and `methodZ()` from the same class `Foo`.

How should I manage this division? Interfaces? Abstract classes? Inheritance? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)/[Aggregation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Aggregation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Aggregation).

first define your interface for Foo collecting all the public methods it should expose from the components:

```
interface Foo
{
   public function methodA();
   public function methodB();
   …
}
```

You could also create interfaces for the components and extend the Foo interface from those, e.g.

```
interface Foo extends FooBar, FooUtility
{}
```

Note: it's not strictly necessary to have an interface collecting the other interfaces or to have an interface for Foo at all. However, since you should [program against an interface and not a concrete implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), it's cleaner.

Then implement that in your conrete Foo implementation:

```
class FooImplementation implements Foo
{
   public function __construct(FooBar $fooBar, FooUtility $fooUtility)
   {
       $this->fooBar = $fooBar;
       $this->fooUtility = $fooUtility;
   }
   public function methodA() 
   { 
       return $this->fooBar->methodA();
   } 
   public function methodB()
   {
       return $this->fooUtility->methodB();
   }
   …
}
```

Inject the various components through the ctor and then just have the methods on Foo delegate to the appropriate components.

You can use use a Factory or Builder to encapsulate creation of the complex Foo type. This will allow you to parametrize the subcomponents:

```
class FooFactory
{
    public function create($param1, $param2)
    {
        return new FooImplementation(
            new FooBar($param1), 
            new FooUtility($param2)
        );
    }
}
```

Note that Factory and Builder are creational patterns. They may control when and how objects are created, so if you want to reuse one of the components in subsequent calls to create, you may add logic to manage the component lifecycles in the factory/builder.

Comment: Isn't there a more flexible and less-hardcoded way? Also my Foo bar cannot accept parameters in the constructor.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli How is this hardcoded?  Why can your `Foo` not accept parameters?

Comment: Jeff: not until PHP 5.4 introduces traits. What you seem to want to achieve is multiple inheritance, and PHP does not support that. The pattern presented here by Gordon is a well accepted solution.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry, It cannot. Foo is a sort of singleton class with a single instance injected in the main application class. (sort of dependency injection).

Comment: @JeffPigarelli What does `Foo` being a singleton have anything to do with passing it parameters?

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry Foo is called through `$this->foo` which trough `__get($class)` magical method returns just a normal single instance of the class `Foo`. All of this is just mechanic and all classes called in this way are well-known no-parameters-singleton classes in my application.

Comment: Words `Singleton` and `Dependency Injection` don't go well together. Just sayin.

Comment: @Mchl, yeah. :P. With "Singleton" I was just referring to a class that should have just one instance, not to the design pattern.

Comment: @Jeff Did you know, Singleton is also brand of whiskey? You can drink one shot of it and it wont hurt. But drink the whole bottle and you cannot maintain yourself anymore. The same is true in programming. Too many singletons will make your code unmaintainable. Get rid of the Singletons. And also get rid of the magic.

Comment: @Gordon, could you please show me an example of use of the class Foo?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli Again, I don't understand why you can't pass these parameters to `Foo`.  I don't agree with your approach using Singletons but this shouldn't prevent you from injecting parameters into it.  When you create the single instance of `Foo` pass `FooUtility` and `FooBar` to it?

Comment: @Gordon, we have already had this conversation, d'you remember? I'm not using Singletons anymore. This "magic" way is just a stupid thing about me wanting to see hot "$this->class" things in my application. Don't even bother. :)

Comment: @JeffPigarelli yeah I remember :) The more suprised I was to see you ask this question. It seems I have to improve my explaining skills ;)

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry, I can't. How would I pass parameters to `$this->foo`? This is a method. I should filter `$class` in `__get($class)` and check whatever `$class = "Foo"` or not then manage it differently. This is kinda crazy and so hardcoded...

Comment: @Gordon, at least I'm not using `Foo::getInstance()`...